# How to typeset a footnote for caption header (caption label) for some figures in a document?

Tags: table-of-contents, floats, captions, footnotes

In a document I am currently writing, my supervisor has asked me to include some meta-information about figures to be typeset as footnotes. I already understand how to handle captions for a floating environment (keep it in a `minipage`, use the optional argument `[]` of `caption` if a `lof` is needed, and then simply use the `footnotemark`/`footnotetext` combo).

Now, here is a twist in the tale.

The footnotes do not correspond to the caption's text i.e. they have nothing to do with caption's content. They represent some meta-info about the figure itself - something like `exif` data of photos or `credits/attribution` information.

My supervisor would like to typeset them as footnotes for the **caption leader**, i.e. the boldfaced header text which says `Figure 2` etc. Furthermore, only a small subset of figures in the document need to have these footnotes. The caption leaders for all other figures must be left untouched.

If that was confusing, here is a minimal working example that does **not** achieve the desired goal (but with some wishful thinking as inline comments).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\begin{document}

% First figure needs footnotes for caption leaders
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\includegraphics{demo}
\caption{First figure. Note the caption with the caption leader} % Should typeset as Figure 1\superscript{1}
\captionleaderfootnote{Some metadata about figure 1}  % This is not a real command, but we need something like this
\end{figure}

% Second figure is a regular figure without any special needs
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\includegraphics{demo}
\caption{Second figure. Nothing special about it}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

My intuition tells me that the `caption` package is the way to go, but I cannot figure out exactly how to hack together a custom `captionleader` for only certain figures. Furthermore, all usual niceties are needed, e.g. this entry needs to go into `lof` without the caption header.  I am open to use `luatex` (maybe any `directlua` magic can be cooked up?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could locally change the labelsep:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\DeclareCaptionLabelSeparator{note}{\footnotemark: }
\begin{document}

% First figure needs footnotes for caption leaders
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\includegraphics{demo}
\captionsetup{labelsep=note}
\caption{First figure. Note the caption with the caption leader} % Should typeset as Figure 1\superscript{1}
%\captionleaderfootnote{Some metadata about figure 1}  % This is not a real command, but we need something like this
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
\includegraphics{demo}
\captionsetup{labelsep=note}
\caption{First figure. Note the caption with the caption leader} % Should typeset as Figure 1\superscript{1}
%\captionleaderfootnote{Some metadata about figure 1}  % This is not a real command, but we need something like this
\end{figure}


% Second figure is a regular figure without any special needs
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\includegraphics{demo}
\caption{Second figure. Nothing special about it}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you for the answer. Much appreciate it. After this is achieved, how can one typeset the actual footnotes? for example in my `mwe`, the text `Some metadata about figure 1` needs to appear in the footnotes within the same page as the figure.

Comment: You wrote in the question that you know how to handle footnotes (I would put the footnote inside the float - in my opinion floats should be selfcontained objects).

Comment: thank you. I shall try this. I was slightly confused about how this would appear in the `lof`. But, it is easy enough for me to try it out and see what happens.

Comment: works like a charm. Thank you. Upvoted and accepted.